# Plotting s-curve function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6hBn.jpg)I would like to plot a basic s-curve. After many hours I learned how to plot a function of x-squared. However I am stumped by how to do this for the s-curve. Thank you very much.

```
p1<- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,2)), aes(x)) + 
stat_function(fun=function(x)x^3, geom="line")
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining cubic and S-curve:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-1, 1)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) x^3, geom = "line")+ 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 1/(1 + exp(-x)), geom = "line")
```

Comment: What if I am hoping to line up the s-curve with the quadratic as in the attached image in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand - do you want S-curve (x^3) with quadratic curve (x^2) in one plot? In your figure, it does not really look like quadratic function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. I want the s-curve with a quadratic in the same plot BUT how do I make it so the curves touch at the end point as shown in the figure?

Comment: What functions do you exactly have? Can you please specify their formulas?

Comment: ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,2)), aes(x)) + 
stat_function(fun=function(x)x^3, geom="line")+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 1/(1 + exp(-x)), geom = "line") However when I plot these together the scale is off and you can't see the s-curve. My goal is to plot it such that the ends of the curves line up. Thanks so much,

Comment: Thanks so much for all your time and attention. Unfortunately I tried that too (modifying the x values) but it didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: In case that this is your desired solution, please accept my answer above